# Possible to get static IP address for the Container deployed to Cloud Run?

Tags: deployment, containers, google-cloud-run, static-ip-address

I would like to deploy a container image to Google Cloud Run (fully managed). I follow the instructions:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy

I was wondering if I can fix static IP for the container or not. Please note that I am not using VM instance. I am new to use this service. I really appreciate it if you could help me on this issue.

Comment: For what do you want a static IP? For the ingress (from internet to your container)? or for the egress (from your container to the internet, typically API calls performed by your container)? If it's for the ingress, why an IP is required? Why the url name is not enough?

Comment: What about egress? Is it possible to fix static IP? For example, the client wants to check the IP for security reason.

Comment: As Ahmet told, it will be possible soon to do something very similar to [that for Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings). Stay tuned!

Answer (score 4):

You can get a static IP for your Cloud Run service (not individual containers, as many containers can be running the same app) by creating a "Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancer" that serves on a static IP and putting your service behind it.

See the [relevant section in documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs#creating_the) on how to create a LB and add a "serverless network endpoint group" behinding it that routes the traffic to Cloud Run.

There's also sample step-by-step guide on this with a load balancer with static IP  at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/multiple-regions.

If you mean "how do I get static IPs for outbound connections my Cloud Run app make", that's a different question with a different answer (it'll be possible soon).

UPDATE (4 Sep 2023):
This is now possible with Static outbound IP address for Google Cloud Run. Documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Run is fully managed serverless containerised service. So you wont get access to IP address. You will get fix URL to the service (hash in the service name is unique to the project-service combination).

Comment: thanks for your reply. If I restart container, does the service URL change? or the same container has always the same URL for each restart?

Comment: It is a service which will have same URL. It manages containers under the hood. If you have many requests it will spin up multiple containers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even if I stop and restart the container, the URL will not change? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes Correct unless you change the service name

Answer (score -2):

This feature is now available for Google Cloud Run services:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip